# insert scc to ascx failed

Tags: asp.net, web, ascx

I encounter a problem.
I am writhing a web site in asp.net
I have a SCC file and I want my user control (ascx) file to use it. 
The thing is that the controller does not recognize the SCC code.

My code in the ascx is:

```
enter code here <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TabsAndLogoUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_WebUserControl" %> <link href="~/App_Themes/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    






<tr>                     
    <td style="  width:30%"> 
    <div class="header_resize">
  <div class="logo">          
        <h1><a><span>Hello</span>Word<small>i need help</small></a></h1>
        <br/><br/>

        </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style=" height: 100%; width:70%">                
    </td>
</tr>
```

Please help me and tell my what is my mistake 
thanks

Comment: Your mistake at the moment is that you haven't asked a clear question. There isn't anything in the code sample you've provided that even relates to the preamble.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the CSS file and your code is incorrect because relative paths are recognized only in server controls.
Try:

```
<link href="App_Themes/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```